# AS3 Value-search an Array using indexOf()

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, variables, shared-objects

In the below code, `indexOf()` is always returning `-1`. The array being searched definately has the values within.

We've tried converting the checked integer into a string in case the array has string formats within, no luck there either.

If anybody could shed any light that would be great!

**AS3**

```
var c:int = 0;
var storedCachesShared:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("cacheStore");
var storedCaches:Array = storedCachesShared.data.cacheArray;
trace(storedCaches); // 1, 2


trace(storedCaches.indexOf(c+1)); // Always returns -1

if(storedCaches.indexOf(c+1) < 0){
    storedCaches.push([c+1]);
    storedCachesShared.flush();
}
```

Many thanks, Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks problematic. It is adding an Array (as you surrounded it with []) to the end of the existing Array:

```
storedCaches.push([c+1]);
```

I think you mean to add an int, so you need this:

```
storedCaches.push(c+1);
```

indexOf is returning -1 because it is looking for an int but storedCaches is an Array of Arrays.